# Center a barcode on a printout

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm printing a receipt with a bar code using jQuery Barcode. No matter what I do I can't center this at the bottom of the receipt, it always appears left aligned. I've tried using a centered Div wrapped around the Barcode like this

html:

```
<div class="bc_center">
    <p id="pr-bcTarget"></p>
</div>
```

css:

```
.bc_center {
   float: none;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

I have also tried a large variety of css options from other StackOverflow suggestions. Nothing works so far.

The  jQuery/JavaScript code creating the bar code looks like this

```
var bar0 = "<div style=\"float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: " + settings.bgColor + "; height: " + mh + "px; width: &Wpx\"></div>";    
var bar1 = "<div style=\"float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: &Wpx solid " + settings.color + "; height: " + mh + "px;\"></div>";
```

I'm certain it has to do with the "float: left", and I tried removing this, of course what happened was each line of the barcode appeared on a separate line.

EDIT: I tried a couple of the suggestions below. The code I have now is just this

```
<span class="bc_center" id="pr-bcTarget"></span>
```

which produces the exact same results as my original. Using Chrome Inspect this is what "jQuery barcode"  is generating...

```
<span class="bc_center" id="pr-bcTarget" style="padding: 0px; overflow: auto; width: 77px;">
    <div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 50px; width: 10px"></div>
    <div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 50px;"></div>
    ... etc ...
    <div style="clear:both; width: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #000000; text-align: center; font-size: 10px; margin-top: 5px;">1179</div>
</span>
```

You'll notice "clear:both" in the final div which allows the barcode number "1179" to be centered, which it does.

Comment: Give some width to that element, otherwise `div` is a block element, takes full width.

Comment: I added the following to the css class. "  width: 50%; " and added some text in the div for good measure. Still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

The magic is in margin:0 auto

Comment: Excellent that worked. I placed in in the Div surrounding the span.

Comment: He already had margin left and right set to `auto`, what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

```
@media print {

    #pr-bcTarget { 
    /*might have to add clear:both I can't tell from here*/
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
   }
}
```

Comment: I just tried that but didn't work. I also tried clear:both still no luck.

Comment: The only other suggestion I would have is to add position:relative